# Java, load jar bytes and use it

Tags: java, jar

Is there a way to load a crypted file (that is a jar file), decrypted it (so obtains the real byte array) and use it without create a file on filesystem and launch it?

```
byte[] jarBytes=Decrypter.decrypt("my\\encrypted\\jar\\file");
//use jarBytes to execute an application without create a real File with this bytes...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

The input stream can come from a resource (i.e., on the classpath). The bytes can be manipulated as required.

See [this post](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-write-custom-class-loader-to.html) for an example of loading the jar from a directory. Your version would be almost identical, except for where the bytes come from originally, and with an additional transformation step.

If anybody is that interested in your code they'll either just a) reverse-engineer your class loader, or b) just use your class loader as-is and not worry about reverse-engineering the encrypted code... but good luck anyway :)

Comment: +1 for the idea that this strategy is pointless (for "protecting da' codez" at least).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for SSCCE; I point people at it often (at least the .org mirror :)

Comment: @Dave Newton: thank you but i'm not looking for a classloader, but a simple "launcher" that execute a jar file after decrypt it. Now i have to save decrypted jar as a temp file to launch it, i'm looking for a way to keep file "in-memory" without save it.

Comment: @blow Yeah, that's a classloader. See [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3574).

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
       Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
       c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
       byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(data);
```